# Self.view calls viewDidLoad in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am new to iPhone Development. Please Help me

I have a view controller calling method from `NSObject` class in the background for view controller when the method calls in that i am creating a view i wrote their `self.view addSubview:view` after this line my view did load calls again.

I dont know why this problem appears please help me here is my code.

**NSObject.m**

```
- (void) showModalMessage:(NSString *)mes
{
  self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            objViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        }
    [objViewController showPopUp:mes];
}

ViewController.m
- (void) showPopUp:(NSString *)mes
{

    labelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(470, 740, 380, 50)];
    [self setLabelViewSettings];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 8, 340, 30)];
    [self setLabelSettings];
    [labelView addSubview:label];
    [label release];
    [self.view addSubview:labelView];// After This line View did load calls again 
    [labelView release];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(hide)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Sorry For my bad english please help me

Comment: Why dont you add the labels in viewDidLoad itself? you can use them later also whenever you want.I also had the same problem and it got solved this way only.

Comment: Where are you calling the `showModalMessage` method? As iPhone Developer says, why not just load your views/labels from the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Your `showModalMessage` method looks very wrong. You are setting the value of self in there, that should only be done inside an initialiser method. You need to include more code - how do you present the view controller on the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclasses of `UIViewController` automatically call `viewDidLoad` whenever the view controller loads its view into memory. View controllers load their views only when needed. So in `[self.view addSubview:labelView]` the `self.view` is causing the view to be loaded into memory and `viewDidLoad` to be called. Immediately before this line the view property must have been nil and accessing the view property with `self.view` automatically loads the view into memory as described in the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Note that `viewDidLoad` can be called multiple times because view controllers may unload their views and set their view property to nil in low memory situations. You need to make sure `viewDidLoad` is safe to call multiple times.

As jrturton pointed out you are setting `self` to a new object in `showModalMessage:`, which is wrong. This guarantees that when you get to `showPopUp:` your newly created `ViewController` object will not have loaded its view yet so you will always call `viewDidLoad` when you hit `self.view`.

Comment: Thanks For nice suggestion. So how would i call this method showpopup because my view controller is present right now and i am calling this method in background.